# "Target Unreachable, identifier 'authenticator' resolved to null" in SEAM

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I am using jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA, authenticator class to authenticate the login process. When I enter the username and password and submit the page, I am getting following error message in my logs:

```
application E javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /login.xhtml @27,76 action="#{authenticator.login()}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'authenticator' resolved to null
 javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /login.xhtml @27,76 action="#{authenticator.login()}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'authenticator' resolved to null
 at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
 at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
```

Following is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" template="layout/noMenuTemplate.xhtml">
<ui:define name="body">
    <div id="content">
                <h:form id="loginForm">
        <rich:panel>
            <f:facet name="header">Login</f:facet>
            <h:messages />
<div class="dialog"><h:panelGrid columns="2" rowClasses="prop"
                columnClasses="name,value">
                <h:outputLabel for="username">Username</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="username" value="#{credentials.username}"
                    style="width: 150px;" />
                <h:outputLabel for="password">Password</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{credentials.password}"
                    style="width: 150px;" />
            </h:panelGrid></div>

            <div class="actionButtons"><h:commandButton id="submit"
                styleClass="button" value="Login" action="#{authenticator.login()}" /></div>
        </rich:panel>
        </h:form>
           </div>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

*Authenticator.java*

```
@Name("authenticator")
@AutoCreate
public class Authenticator {    
    @Logger Log log;
    @In Identity identity;
    @In Credentials credentials;
    @In Session hibernateSession;

    public Authenticator() {}

    public void login() throws IOException {
        log.debug("calling login method ............... ");

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

        StringBuffer location = new StringBuffer(request.getContextPath());
        location.append("/j_security_check?j_username=");
        location.append((credentials.getUsername() != null) ? credentials.getUsername() : "");
        location.append("&j_password=");
        location.append((credentials.getPassword() != null) ? credentials.getPassword() : "");

        log.debug("LOCATION : " + location.toString());

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(location.toString()));      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Authenticator class appears to be implemented correctly. I'd search further up in your logs and find out why it isn't being created.

Also, I'd suggest posting the relevant section from components.xml. Should be something like:

```
<security:identity authenticate-method="#{authenticator.login}"/>
```

Comment: <security:identity authenticate-method="#{authenticator.authenticate}" remember-me="true" jaas-config-name="mylogin" />

Comment: In components.xml, you are telling it to call `#{authenticator.authenticate}`, but your Authenticator class doesn't have an `authenticate()` method. Try changing it to `#{authenticator.login}`